Why did "Beetlejuice" avoid using his own name?
In Beetlejuice movie, we see Beetlejuice trying to coerce Adam and Barbra to say the word "Beetlejuice" but does it in indirect way, like deliberately miss-spelling and choosing words that rhyme with beetlejuice.
I looked into it but could only deduce that Beetlejuice can't use the word himself. I don't know what would happen if he did. The word must be spoken by someone else.
Why did Beetlejuice go through all of the trouble and not directly tell them exactly what to say?

I think it's related to the fact that his name has to be said three times to allow him to enter the living world (this answer elaborates on this). With this rule in place it makes sense that he cannot say his own name, this way it's harder for him to convince or trick someone to bring him to the living world.

Per The Musical, he outright states that he can't say it. No explanation is offered for why... Lydia: I don't know your name" Beetlejuice: Well, I can't say it

The script of the movie says (emphasis added):

BETELGEUSE I can't help you from this side, but here's how we do it.  So simple. Say my name three times. That's all. I'll be all yours. Then I'll bring you over here in style.
LYDIA: I... I don't know what your name is.
BETELGEUSE: Minor problem. The rules. I can't tell it to you.  But.. do you know how to play charades?

The "rules" here are implied strongly to be that he's not allowed to say his own name. Just from this we can't say what would happen to him if he did say his own name (presumably at the very least then if someone who heard the name from him said it three times it wouldn't actually work to let him into the world of the living), or if he's even capable of saying his own name. There's no explicit mention of a "curse" in the film, though it seems reasonable to assume that he received some form of banishment because of his mischievous nature.
Here's a YouTube clip of that scene:



The transcript here is quite different from the script, presumably Michael Keaton did some ad-libbing. Instead of talking about "the rules" he said:

If I tell you, you'll tell your friends, your friends are calling me on the horn all the time and I gotta show up at shopping centers for openings, sign autographs and shit like that and it makes my life a hell. Ok? A living hell. But maybe, you have a pen— oh I know you can play charades?

Arguably this is more comedic, and while it's clear Betelgeuse is making things up here (there's no logic to the notion that he can't say it because she will tell her friends as guessing the name has the same result), maybe he thinks talking about the rules wouldn't be very convincing for the teenager Lydia.
If he could just say his own (mostly unguessable) name, or if he could just say it so that someone else could say it, what would be the point of using that mechanism to prevent him from crossing over?
It's worth noting that this concept of the saying of a character's weird name holding power is similar to the story of Rumpelstiltskin as well as Mister Mxyzptik from Superman comics (first appearance 1944).
Also the concept of summoning spirits by repeating their name multiple times has its origin in folklore, for example Bloody Mary.

In the original script he happily says his name after having been summoned; https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/beetlejuice_mcdowell.html

There's also no notion of repeating his name three times in there. They just dig up and open his grave.

@shim & Valorum - The early version is known as the dark version, with two sisters, early drowning, middle eastern Beetle Juice. Warren Skaaren was brought in for re-writes: he blended cathy and Lydia into one, added more of the human and joke stuff, changed Beetle Juice into the character that Keaton got to flesh out, and more than likely added the three name stuff. The three name, calls, anything, is popular in both Western and Eastern mythology, folklore, horror. McDowell was quoted as loving Chinese horror as he could steal from it (back in '84 that was probably ok to say).

With the 'rule' there probably isn't anything nefarious that happens to him if he says it: he probably just gets yanked back to the waiting room and really doesn't have much fun there.

Since it's never been explicitly stated it's anybody's guess.

As far as I'm informed the curse made him unable to say his own name. That seems like part of the punishment but an explanation as to why it might be relevant is not given. Maybe like someone else said it might be to avoid him being able to directly trick someone into calling out his name. It's harder to call someone by his name if he himself can't tell you how he is called.
That's from the Beetlejuice Wiki:

In the episode "The Wizard of Ooze," Beetlejuice actually says his own name for the first time. According to his curse, he is unable to do so. However, the episode is revealed to have been a dream sequence, which likely accounts for the discrepancy.


Can you offer any evidence to back this up, or is it merely your own opinion?

"In the episode "The Wizard of Ooze," Beetlejuice actually says his own name for the first time. According to his curse, he is unable to do so. However, the episode is revealed to have been a dream sequence, which likely accounts for the discrepancy."
That's from the Beetlejuice Wiki:
https://beetlejuice.fandom.com/wiki/Beetlejuice_(character)
Did you downvote my comment? A quick Google search could have told anyone who doubts my comments. smh

If you have downvoted my comment I would urge you to undo it. I provided the links. Something anyone could just have quickly looked up by the way.

You haven't supplied any direct evidence (fan wiki don't count) for your first statement.

@EbonyPope it takes some time to get used to the voting in Stack Exchange. In this particular SE site it sometimes feels like "everyone's a critic" and down votes are distributed generously. Don't let it worry you too much. " Anyone can look it up" is just not how Stack Exchange answers work. Stack Exchange is different than most other Q&A sites; answer posts need to go further to support their assertions. It takes some time to get used to, but  the long run it's worth it. Welcome to Stack Exchange!

@EbonyPope also, "Who the hell downvoted my comment?" is not part of an answer so it should't be in an answer post. You can move it to a comment, but it's still useless except to start fights, and that can potentially get you banned quickly. Stack Exchange is not for everyone, and certainly not a place to engage in argumentative exchanges with other users the way, say, comments under YouTube videos are sometimes used.
